# Running Azure-cli commands from python script

Tags: python, azure, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I have these azure-cli2 (which is python based) commands for creating rbac user and few other activities

```
az ad user create --display-name "user" --password Pass@word1 --user-principal-name "user@test.onmicrosoft.com"  --mail-nickname user
az role assignment create --role Contributor --assignee "user@test.onmicrosoft.com"
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "testapp"
```

I am using the `subprocess.check_output()` to run these commands from python.

Is there any way directly initiate azure-cli commands from python

I am expecting for something like this:

```
import azure-core-cli
azure-core-cli.mycommand(param)
```

PS: I know ,I can get same functionality using azure Python SDK

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better idea to use Azure SDK directly in your script? After all the CLI is written as an application instead of a library.

Comment: @Troy Dai I will but that will take some time and till then I have to use this version with the variation suggested by Alex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Azure CLI commands using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51546073/how-to-run-azure-cli-commands-using-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this file](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/dev/src/azure-cli/azure/cli/__main__.py), try:

```
from azure.cli.core import get_default_cli

get_default_cli().invoke(['ad', 'user', 'create', '--display-name', 'user', ...])
```