# Copy files from blob container to another container using python

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-python

I am trying to copy 'specific files' from one folder to another. when I am trying to use Wild card operator (*) at the end, the copy does not happen.

But if I provide just the folder name, then all the files from this source folder are copied to target folder without any issues.

Problem: File copy does not happen when Wild card operator is used.
Can you please help me to fix the problem?

```
def copy_blob_files(account_name, account_key, copy_from_container, copy_to_container, copy_from_prefix):
  try:
    blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=account_name, account_key=account_key)
    files = blob_service.list_blobs(copy_from_container, prefix=copy_from_prefix)

    for f in files:
      #print(f.name)
      blob_service.copy_blob(copy_to_container, f.name.replace(copy_from_prefix,""), f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{copy_from_container}/{f.name}")
  except:
    print('Could not copy files from source to target')

copy_from_prefix = 'Folder1/FileName_20191104*.csv'
copy_blob_files (accountName, accesskey, copy_fromcontainer, copy_to_container, copy_from_prefix)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `copy_blob` method does not support wildcard.

**1**.If you want to copy specified pattern of blobs, you can filter the blobs in `list_blobs()` method with prefix(it also does not support wildcard). In your case, the prefix looks like `copy_from_prefix = 'Folder1/FileName_20191104'`, note that there is no wildcard.

The code below works at my side, and all the specified pattern files are copies and blob name replaced:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

account_name ="xxx"
account_key ="xxx"

copy_from_container="test7"
copy_to_container ="test4"

#remove the wildcard
copy_from_prefix = 'Folder1/FileName_20191104'

def copy_blob_files(account_name, account_key, copy_from_container, copy_to_container, copy_from_prefix):
    try:
        block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name,account_key)
        files = block_blob_service.list_blobs(copy_from_container,copy_from_prefix)
        for file in files:
            block_blob_service.copy_blob(copy_to_container,file.name.replace(copy_from_prefix,""),f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{copy_from_container}/{file.name}")

    except:
        print('could not copy files')

copy_blob_files(account_name,account_key,copy_from_container,copy_to_container,copy_from_prefix)
```

**2**.Another way as others mentioned, you can use python to call azcopy(you can use [azcopy v10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json), which is just a .exe file). And for using wildcard in azcopy, you can follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json#use-wildcard-characters-1). Then you write you own azcopy command, at last, write your python code as below:

```
import subprocess

#the path of azcopy.exe, v10 version
exepath = "D:\\azcopy\\v10\\azcopy.exe"

myscript= "your azcopy command"

#call the azcopy command
subprocess.call(myscript)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your inputs. I like the first option and I tested with my files. It worked well :)

Answer (score 0):

AzCopy supports wildcards, you could excute AzCopy from your Python code.

An example of how to do this can be found here: [How to run Azure CLI commands using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51546073/how-to-run-azure-cli-commands-using-python)

Comment: I doubt if this is available in azure sdk..https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/6306