# Login to python script using service principal

Tags: python, azure, azure-service-principal, runbook

I have registered one App in AAD, I got its App ID. I did role assignment for this app as "owner of a particular subscription"

Now from Azure Runbook I want to run  my python script and use this App credentials to login. My python script has az cli commands.
So I don't want to use powershell command for login.
I'm trying to use below command:

Az login --service-principal -u $azureapplucationId -p $azurePassword --tenant $azuretenantId

But I'm not getting any method to convert the azurepassword to secureString.

Is there any way to login using service Principal ID  in python script?

Answer (score 2):

After deploying in my environment, if you want to login using service principal ID in python script, you need to install `azure.cli.core` module packages in your python script terminal by using

```
pip install azure.cli.core
```

Below is my python script taken [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62983437/authenticating-azure-cli-with-python-sdk) from
@Jim Xu, to login into azure cloud using service principal:

> ```
>    from azure.cli.core import get_default_cli
>     az_cli = get_default_cli()
>     az_cli.invoke(['login', '--service-principal', '-u', '<app ID/clientID>', '-p', '<clientsecretvalue>','--tenant','<tenantID>'])
> ```

- Create an `app->get an app ID`
- Click on app and create a `new client secret`

  Certifications & secrets->new client secret->copy        the obtained client secret value.
- Under App Registrations > Your app > App Role > Provide the below details:

[image]

**Output**:

You need to run visual studio code as "run as administrator"

[image]