# How to run command from variable instead of those line in python?

Tags: python, azure, azure-cli

I have below commands for run az aks command:

```
from azure.cli.core import get_default_cli
az_cli = get_default_cli()
res = az_cli.invoke(['login', '--service-principal', '-u', client_id, '-p', client_secret,'--tenant',tenant_id])
az_cli.invoke(['aks','command','invoke','--resource-group',resourcegroup,'--name',clustername,'--command','kubectl apply -f',outfile_final])
```

I want as below,

```
azcmd = "az login --service-principal -u " + client_id + " -p " + client_secret + " --tenant " + tenant_id

**res = az_cli.invoke([azcmd])**
```

but Above script is giving error like **args should be a list or tuple**,
and 2nd error:
[image]
Is there anyways to run invoke with get input from variable.

Edit1:
I'm applying deployment file as below:

```
namespace = "kubectl apply -f abc.yaml"
```

Comment: Could please Elaborate what are you trying? Are you trying to create aks cluster Via CLI?

Comment: @RithwikBojja , question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

Initially I tried with same command and got same error:

[image]

I installed azure-cli module in my local machine, Also instead of using -

```
res = az_cli.invoke([azcmd])
```

You can add your **`azcmd`** inside ([ ])

```
from  azure.cli.core  import  get_default_cli
az_cli = get_default_cli()
cmd=(['login', '--service-principal', '-u', client_id, '-p', client_secret,'--tenant',tenant_id])

res=az_cli.invoke(cmd)
```

> Is there anyways to run invoke with get input from variable.

With above code I can invoke with get input from variable.

**Console:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Authenticating Azure CLI with Python SDK - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62983437/authenticating-azure-cli-with-python-sdk) by Jim Xu.

Comment: Venkatesan, Thanks for the response. az login is working fine but below command is not working ----------------
namespace1 = "nirav"
    az_cli.invoke(['aks','command','invoke',resourcegroup,'--name',clustername,'--command','kubectl delete namespaces',namespace1])

Comment: Hi @microset I tried with above mentioned commands in my environment, and it executed successfully.here is my [Snapshot](https://i.imgur.com/n8XpNBK.png)

Comment: Thanks again Venkatesan , Can you please send me line no 4 from the you send the link of snapshot https://i.imgur.com/n8XpNBK.png , I need to check what is wrong with my code.

Comment: yeah, here it is cmd=az_cli.invoke(['aks','command','invoke','--resource-group','myResourceGroup','--name','myAKSCluster','--command','kubectl delete namespaces namespace1'])

Comment: Here is my full code:

    from  azure.cli.core  import  get_default_cli
    az_cli = get_default_cli()
    
    az_cli.invoke(['login', '--service-principal', '-u','client-id', '-p', 'client secret','--tenant','tenant-id'])
    cmd=(['aks','command','invoke','--resource-group','myResourceGroup','--name','myAKSCluster','--command','kubectl delete namespaces namespace1'])
    res=az_cli.invoke(cmd)

Comment: Thanks Once Again for spend your valuable for my issue. Issue is resolved now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250788/discussion-between-microset-and-venkatesan).