# Azure-Devops API Calls in Python

Tags: python, jenkins, azure-devops

I'm currently trying to setup a Jenkins pipeline which kicks off a Python script I'm writing. In this Python script, I need to figure out how to use Azure DevOps API calls. For example, the first task I'm trying to do is download an Artifact.

The typical azure-cli command to do this would be:

```bsh
az artifacts universal download --organization \"https://dev.azure.com/yourorg/\" --feed yourfeed --name your_artifact --version * --path .
```

Does anyone know how to write out azure-devops api calls in Python?

Comment: Az CLI is not REST API. Behind the scene it uses it but please can you tell us if your intention is to use Az CLI or [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51551313/11508192). we could invoke the Azure CLI with following way. For example:

```
from azure.cli.core import get_default_cli
get_default_cli().invoke(['artifacts', 'universal', 'download', '--organization', '\"https://dev.azure.com/yourorg/\"', '--feed', 'yourfeed', '--name', 'your_artifact', '--version', '*', '--path'])
```

If you get `No module named 'azure.cli.command_modules'` error, please install `azure-cli`.

To start using the Azure DevOps extension for Azure CLI,please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/?view=azure-devops).

On how to call azure-cli from python script,you can also refer to this [sample](https://gist.github.com/ainamori/d6c517f2f1e8f588eab39d529cd09501) on github.

Comment: I was heading down this path but I ran into that issue you notated where it states no module named azure. I installed azure-cli and the devops extension previously on my Jenkins host where these scripts are running but still receive this error.

Here is my az --version output:
azure-cli                         2.10.1

command-modules-nspkg              2.0.3
core                              2.10.1
nspkg                              3.0.4
telemetry                          1.0.4

Extensions:
azure-devops                      0.18.0

Comment: I'm not sure if this affects anything, but I forgot to mention our Jenkins setup runs in a Docker container.