# Alternatives for azure-iot-hub python package

Tags: python, azure, azure-iot-hub, pypi

The azure-iot-hub python package hasn't had any updates in last 2 years, and depends on deprecated azure-uamqp-python that is failing to build on systems such as Mac ARM and Linux ARM on Python 3.12+.

So, is there any alternative to replace it?

Reference:
https://github.com/ansible-collections/azure/pull/1512

Edited:
Currently I have no problem with that. I am looking for an alternative in case of possible removing of this package from Ansible collection.

Comment: Edit the question to include [desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This will help others answer the question.

Comment: AFAIK the answer is no.

Comment: @Mosy Mosy Other way is to use rest [Apis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/). let me what your requirement

Comment: @Sampath I am currently working with Azure IoT Hub to create device, and perform getting and updating twin tasks. I think the best option might be to implement an interface using the azure-cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps below outline how to set up Azure IoT Hub and manage devices using Azure CLI commands:

- To log into your Azure account, use the Azure CLI and execute the following command:

```
az login
```

[image]

- **Create IoT Hub**: If you haven't created an IoT Hub yet, you can create one using the Azure CLI:

```
az iot hub create --name <hub_name> --resource-group <resource_group_name> --sku S1
```

[image]

- Refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/iot/hub/device-identity?view=azure-cli-latest#az-iot-hub-device-identity-create) to create, list, update, and delete devices using Azure CLI.

**Create Device**:

```
az iot hub device-identity create --hub-name <hub_name> --device-id <device_id>
```

[image]

**List Devices**:

```
az iot hub device-identity list --hub-name <hub_name>
```

[image]

- **Get Device Twin**:

```
az iot hub device-twin show --device-id <device_id> --hub-name <hub_name>
```

[image]

- refer this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/iot/hub/device-twin?view=azure-cli-latest#az-iot-hub-device-twin-update) to get and update device twin properties using Azure CLI.
- **Update Device Twin**:

```
az iot hub device-twin update --device-id
                              [--add]
                              [--auth-type {key, login}]
                              [--desired]
                              [--etag]
                              [--force-string]
                              [--hub-name]
                              [--login]
                              [--remove]
                              [--resource-group]
                              [--set]
                              [--tags]
```

[image]

[image]

- Refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51546073/how-to-run-azure-cli-commands-using-python) to How to run Azure CLI commands using python

Comment: Thanks @Sampath. Last night I implemented an interface like azure-iot-hub using the azure-cli